# concatenate using enumerator and join in Julia

Tags: python-3.x, string, julia

I have a dictionary in Julia named

```
Cols = {'Employee': 'varchar(255)',
 'Sex': 'varchar(255)',
 'Designation': 'varchar(255)',
 'Code': 'varchar(255)',
 'Salary': 'int'}
```

I want to join it in julia as -

```
'Employee varchar(255),Sex varchar(255),Designation varchar(255),Code varchar(255),Salary int'
```

In python I can do it by the following code-

```
cols = ",".join([f'{k} {v}' for k, v in cols.items()])
```

What's the alternative way in Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it that is similar to your Python code:

```
Cols = Dict("Employee" => "varchar(255)",
            "Sex" => "varchar(255)",
            "Designation" => "varchar(255)",
            "Code" => "varchar(255)",
            "Salary" => "int")

join(("$k $v" for (k, v) in Cols), ",")
```